# How to invert sorting arrows? Aka sorting arrows are wrong

Tags: themes, system-settings, sort

In a table, I feel the sort indicator symbol is wrong. I want:

- ▲ = ASC
- ▼ = DESC

(or maybe even the other way around - depending on your needs)

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

`~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` or `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` should contain:

```
[Settings]
gtk-alternative-sort-arrows = true
```

### Long answer

Open:

- `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (settings for one user only)
- OR: `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` (settings for all users).

If the file does not exist, create it.

Make the file contain at least:

```
[Settings]
gtk-alternative-sort-arrows = true
```

(If the file is already existed, add `gtk-alternative-sort-arrows = true` below `[Settings]`.)

### Discussion references on the topic

- https://hackernoon.com/sorting-arrow-confusion-in-data-tables-5a3117698fdf
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1008
- https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/-/issues/1848